# Urban cultivation manhua where the void emperor from "I'm the Great Immortal" is the MC

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, cultivation

It's a typical urban cultivation manhua where an immortal reincarnates as a mortal in the city, but there is a chapter where the MC and the heroines from "I'm the Great Immortal" meets the MC of this manhua. This scene suddenly came up in my head, and I wanted to know which manhua it was.

The MC of this manhua was overpowered like the MC from "I'm the Great Immortal", and the conversation between the two MCs in that one chapter indicated they were equal in strength and that the MC of this manhua is called the void emperor by the MC of "I'm the Great Immortal". I'm pretty sure there is no relations between the two manhua story-wise since it was only one chapter where they met and I never read "I'm the Great Immortal", but I'm not sure if that was a canon chapter related to the story of this manhua.

I'm can't recall much other than that this manhua is an urban cultivation manhua where the MC is an overpowered immortal reincarnate going around the city being what any typical MC of this kind of manhua does, like going to auctions. I'm sorry if this doesn't give much, but I would really appreciate it if you can help me find this manhua. It's been bugging me a lot .

Comment: Do you recall in roughly which chapter the MC from _I'm the Great Immortal_ appeared? If you could indicate a range of chapters at least, that could be helpful in IDing the correct manhua.

Comment: If I'm being honest, I'm not too sure since it's just a memory I remembered. But, it was quite a bit in, not a lot, I would say around Chapter 60 - 70? Maybe 40? It was before Chapter 100 or so (max 110 or 120). I can't be too sure, which is why the chapters are broad, but I'm pretty sure it's more likely between Chapters 60-90. I hope this helps. If not, then I apologize.

Comment: That's better than nothing, thank you.